# Transforming subquery to INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, subquery

Transforming the following query (with subquery)

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE t1.a IN (SELECT t2.b FROM t2 where t2.c = 1)
```

.. to this query with INNER JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.a = t2.b AND t2.c = 1
```

I can get a nice performance boost (learned at http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/03/25/mysql-in-query-performance)

But how about a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE t1.a NOT IN (SELECT t2.b FROM t2 where t2.c <> 1)
```

Note for the "NOT IN" and "<>". Can I achieve something similar?

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope it's better now.

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Does it work the way you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
ON t1.a = t2.b
WHERE t2.b IS NULL OR t2.c = 1
```

EDIT: I accidentally wrote **INNER** join. Sorry; it should be **LEFT OUTER** join.